# Should I bind my WinForm textboxes to local variables, to some data entity, or write helper functions to get the values

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am writing a c# winforms app that makes a couple of rest calls to a web service.

I have several textboxes with different behaviours. To take a specific example, one is called `txtPrice`. I have two buttons that increase or decrease the price across an (uneven) range of permissible values (`btnIncrease` and `btnDecrease`).

I need to parse the value in `txtPrice` to send it to the webservice. I have thought of three ways of doing this, and I would like some advice (or perhaps a pointer to look at a different way of doing it).

1. Have form-scope variables (`private double price;`) which are updated on `txtPrice_Validated`. I like this method as it separates the view from the model, but I dislike it because the data is duplicated. Also every time I update the price using the buttons I have to update it in two places.
2. Use member functions `myForm.getPrice()` and `myForm.setPrice()` which update `txtPrice`. Something about this seems ugly, storing data as strings, but it seems pragmatic.
3. Perhaps there is a kind of (non-database) entity I can bind to, which could encapsulate this logic?

More generally - is there a simple tutorial book which teaches a few basic exercises like this?

Comment: It sounds as though you replicated the function of a form level property with out the benefit of being able to easily bind to it.  Why not make "Price" a property, implement `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`, and bind the textbox to the property.  Also, I would recommend you use the decimal type instead of double.

Comment: Thanks very much, this was what I was looking for.